# CSS selector only for Flying saucer

Tags: java, html, css, pdf, flying-saucer

Is there exists CSS selector that works only when transforming html to pdf with flying saucer, and doesn't work when opening this html?
I need something like this

```
@page OnlyForFlyingSaucer {
    body {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating PDF with flying saucer is treated as "print" media, see the [CSS 2.1 specification section on media types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html).

The syntax will be:

```
@media print {
    body {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}
```